# How to differentiate between databases dumps?

Tags: python, mysql, database, oracle, dump

Am trying to write a python tool, that helps me to automate importing databases dumps into my current DB.

But my question is, if I have a directory that has more than one dump, and I don't know what the database type of those dumps, oracle or mysql or whatever!

Is there a way to know types of dumps with python?

Comment: if you don't know what type it is, how is python going to work it out? I'd suggest grabing a dump from each type of database under a few different dump options and examining the differences.

Comment: @danblack
The idea is that this tool should also differentiate between dumps types automatically!

Comment: right, so get some known samples, you can work it out, then you can encapsulate your learning in the python program you are creating. Happy coding. Welcome to SO.